# How can I use the "Save as" option in Spyder?

Tags: 14.04, python, menu, spyder

I've recently switched from using Spyder in Windows to Ubuntu 14.04 to edit Python (.py) scripts. In Windows, one could choose File -> Save as, to save the .py file under any name. In Linux, however, there is no "File" button, only an "New" "Open" "Save" and "Save all" button (see below).

I would like to not just save the .py script but also change its name and directory, so I need a "Save as" option. How can I access this in Ubuntu?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer

In Ubuntu We have what we call the "global menu", which becomes visible when you move the mouse to the top of the screen. There you will find it:

[image]

By default, global menu is *enabled*, and the menu is not attached to the window. If you'd like to change that, go to *System Settings* > *Appearance pane* and choose where you want your app menus to appear (on mouse over).

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for your answer; this was indeed the case. (I also changed the placing of the menu to the 'local' window as you indicated).

Comment: @khpeek we are so used to it, that we forget it is different from other DE's :)